# Problems in saving contents of datagridview to database

Tags: c#

I'm developing a simple database related application. The GUI consists of datagrid view and a "save" button. The datagridview uses a  dataset as its source. The dataset is in turn populated by fetching data from a SQL Server Compact Edition database file.

The problem is when i make changes to content of database using the datagridview and then proceed to change it.

```
SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
da.UpdateCommand = Con.CreateCommand(); // Con is SqlCeCommand object
da.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "update TempTable set " +
"S.No = @S.No , Name = @Name";

this.AddParams(da.UpdateCommand, "S.No", "Name");
da.Update(ds); // ds is the dataset used as source by the datagridview
```

and AddParams Method ...

```
private void AddParams(SqlCeCommand cmd, params string[] cols)
        {
            foreach (string col in cols)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@" + col, SqlDbType.Char, 0, col);
            }
        }
```

Problem is i'm getting an ArguementException with description as "char" in the following line

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@" + col, SqlDbType.Char, 0, col);
```

i believe is due to the fact that one of the parameter is a varchar while the other is an integer. So how i get this done ?

p.s. i'm a beginner in Dot Net & Programming.

Comment: have you tried removing the the dot `.` on S.No? maybe the parser is trip up with it, and the `@` in cmd.Parameters.Add is optional, you can remove it

Answer (score 0):

If its just the type which causes the problem you could define a individual type for each column like this:

```
Dictionary<string, SqlDbType> columnDefinition = new Dictionary<string, SqlDbType>( )
{
    { "S.No", SqlDbType.YourType },
    { "Name", SqlDbType.OtherType }
};

private void AddParams( SqlCeCommand cmd, params string[] cols )
{
    foreach( string col in cols )
    {
       cmd.Parameters.Add( "@" + col, columnDefinition[ col ], 0, col );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you are not providing the db value size as u are provinding 0 to it.

provide size or just just @paraname, value

for more info 
reffer to 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.aspx

Comment: if you are not defining the size (0), the default is max; meaning, the adapter won't do additional length checking when you save things to database.  it's safe to leave it as 0